# Robot Framework with Python Locating a link in an email

Tags: python, robotframework

I am using the Robot Framework with Python and I need to write a test to select a link in an email sent to a gmail account. I was going to  use the ImapLibrary but after researching it. The commands for selecting a link from an email do not seem to work.

Since I am new to both Robot and Python does anyone have a suggestion on how to approach this.

Thanks
Keith